# .NET (Core) on Unix: In-process modification of environment variables via P/Invoke system calls is unexpectedly not seen by .NET

Tags: c#, unix, .net-core, environment-variables, pinvoke

A notable limitation of the .NET environment-variable APIs as of .NET 8 is the inability to define environment variables *without a value* or, to put it differently, with a value that is the *empty string*.

Both Windows and Unix-like platforms do support this natively, however, via system calls, which is why calling the latter directly is of interest.

- Bringing this ability to .NET itself in the future is the subject of [GitHub issue #50554](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/50554).

While using P/Invoke declarations to access the relevant system calls works as expected on Windows, it does not on Unix-like platforms, as of .NET 8:

- .NET does not *see* the P/Invoke-mediated environment modifications and continues to report the *old* environment, both via `Environment` and when launching child processes.

Is this a bug, or is the code below missing something?

---

Sample C# console-application code, tested with version 8.0.101 of the .NET SDK:

- Run on a Unix-like platform (Linux or MacOS), as the content of the `Program.cs` file in a project created with `dotnet new console`
- Add `<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>` inside the `<PropertyGroup>` element of the `*.csproj` file in order for the project to compile.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

partial class Program
{
  [LibraryImport("libc", StringMarshalling = StringMarshalling.Utf8)]
  private static partial int setenv(string name, string value, int overwrite);

  [LibraryImport("libc", StringMarshalling = StringMarshalling.Utf8)]
  private static partial IntPtr getenv(string name); // Convert to string with Marshal.PtrToStringUTF8()

  [LibraryImport("libc", StringMarshalling = StringMarshalling.Utf8)]
  private static partial int system(string command);

  static void ThrowSysCallError() => throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastSystemError());

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    // Define / set env. var. 'FOO' with / to value 'new' 
    if (-1 == setenv("FOO", "new", 1)) ThrowSysCallError();

    Console.WriteLine(
      $"In-process value of FOO after setting it to 'new', via syscall: [{Marshal.PtrToStringUTF8(getenv("FOO"))}]"
    );

    Console.Write(
      "Value of FOO in a syscall-launched child process: "
    );
    system("echo [$FOO]");

    Console.WriteLine(
      $"In-process value of FOO per Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(\"FOO\"): [{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FOO")}]"
    );

    Console.Write(
      "Value of FOO in a .NET-launched child process: "
    );
    Process.Start(
      new ProcessStartInfo()
      {
        FileName = "sh",
        ArgumentList = { "-c", @"echo [$FOO]" },
      }
    )?.WaitForExit();

  }

}
```

The *expected* output would be:

```
In-process value of FOO after setting it to 'new', via syscall: [new]
Value of FOO in a syscall-launched child process: [new]
In-process value of FOO per Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FOO"): [new]
Value of FOO in a .NET-launched child process: [new]
```

The *actual* output is - note how .NET apparently doesn't see the `FOO` variable that the `setenv()` syscall set:

```
In-process value of FOO after setting it to 'new', via syscall: [new]
Value of FOO in a syscall-launched child process: [new]
In-process value of FOO per Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FOO"): []
Value of FOO in a .NET-launched child process: []
```

Comment: What is the output of the example code on Windows? The documentation at [`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-environment-getenvironmentvariable) would seem to indicate that `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` will not find a variable set via `setenv()` on Windows either.

Comment: @JonathanDodds, the example code cannot be run on Windows, due to using Unix system calls. However, as implied (but not spelled out) in the question, using the equivalent system call on Windows([`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setenvironmentvariable)) _does_ work as intended. I don't think that the linked documentation states what you think it does: it doesn't mention platform-native system calls at all.

Comment: The documentation indicates that it is likely that the implementation uses a cache -- which is confirmed by @NPras in their answer.

Comment: @JonathanDodds, the information is currently _missing_ from [the article  you linked to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-environment-getenvironmentvariable), and also from the `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` topic. (Only the _inverse_ problem - not being able to set env. vars. _for_ native libraries - is documented, in `SetEnvironmentVariable`). I've created  [GitHub docs issue #39448](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/39448) to get that fixed. As for the _why_ of this behavior: I've added background information in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an interesting rabbit hole, thank you.

If we look at the runtime source, [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5d3a3c1e5d3185e1e1b169e0a3479326963f4d69/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Environment.cs#L42) gets delegated to the platform-specific `GetEnvironmentVariableCore`.

[On Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5d3a3c1e5d3185e1e1b169e0a3479326963f4d69/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Environment.Variables.Windows.cs#L13), this results in the appropriate interop call to `Kernel32` (also when `Set`-ing). Nothing to see there.

---

[On Unix](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5d3a3c1e5d3185e1e1b169e0a3479326963f4d69/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Environment.Variables.Unix.cs#L17), things look a little more interesting. It contains a `static` dictionary cache `s_environment`. If we're *very* lucky and it hasn't been populated yet, we'll get our desired interop call to `getenv`.

Unfortunately, any call to `GetEnvironmentVariables` (the plural version) and `SetEnvironmentVariable` will populate the cache - courtesy of `EnsureEnvironmentCached`.

Once that happens, all operations will happen on the cache. So if *anything in the runtime* has called either of them (it does. in so many places), we're out of luck.

This explains our first missing value. Calling `GetEnvironmentVariable` will likely end up with us being served a cached value, skipping the `getenv` call.

---

But what about the child process? Shouldn't that inherit the process's environment - which we *did* set via `setenv`?

If only we were so lucky. Like before, `Process.Start()` gets delegated to the platform-specific `StartCore`. [Here it is in all its glory](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f4fa259f10762430bc555506f1640cb17b3f2e4f/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.Unix.cs#L367). Now notice the `string[] envp = CreateEnvp(startInfo);` line. If we keep digging, this `envp` keeps getting passed deeper, eventually ending up in the [`execve` syscall](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f4fa259f10762430bc555506f1640cb17b3f2e4f/src/native/libs/System.Native/pal_process.c#L424), after `fork`ing.

This is a problem because [`CreateEnvp`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f4fa259f10762430bc555506f1640cb17b3f2e4f/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.Unix.cs#L611) gets its values from [`ProcessStartInfo.Environment`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f4fa259f10762430bc555506f1640cb17b3f2e4f/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/ProcessStartInfo.cs#L91), which gets its values from... our good friend `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()` which we know from the last episode will serve us cached values.

---

The take home message from all this is that, in Unix/Linux, we should be safe if we stick to `Environment.[Set,Get]EnvironmentVariable` calls, as we'll be confined to operating with cached values.

But as you've established in your question, we're out of luck if we want to use empty variables.

Answer (score 1):

[NPras' excellent sleuthing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77951883/45375) has unearthed the *de facto* behavior of .NET; let me add some **background information**:

On **Unix**-like platforms - unlike on Windows - .**NET *by design* maintains a *private copy of the process' original environment-variable block* that only *managed* code can see and modify**,<sup>[1]</sup> which has the following **ramifications** with respect to (in-process) **calls to *native libraries***:

- Native libraries (called via P/Invoke) **do *not* see changes to the managed process' environment variables** that are later performed in-process by managed callers with `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`.

  - That is, any code in native libraries that *queries* the process environment (of necessity via *system calls* such as [`getenv`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html)) sees the *original* process environment, not the modified private copy maintained by .NET.
  - This is (tersely) documented, namely in [`System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable):

    - > On non-Windows systems, calls to the `SetEnvironmentVariable(String, String)` method have no effect on any native libraries that are, or will be, loaded.
- Native libraries **cannot modify the environment of a managed caller**.

  - That is, any code in native libraries that *modifies* the process environment (of necessity via *system calls* such as [`setenv`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html)) has *no* effect on a manage caller.
  - As of this writing, this is *not* documented, neither in the documentation for the [`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable) method, nor in the [`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-environment-getenvironmentvariable) fundamentals article.

    - [GitHub docs issue #39448](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/39448) aims to change that.

---

The **design rationale** is purely **one of *technical necessity***:

- On Unix-like platforms, the environment variable-related system calls *are NOT guaranteed to be thread-safe*.
- While explicit synchronization of access to environment variables is possible, its use cannot be *guaranteed*: native libraries could perform unsynchronized access.
- .NET therefore decided to create its own, managed environment "world", where thread safety *can* be guaranteed (because only managed callers can access it).
- For background information, see:

  - [The `setenv` fiasco](https://www.club.cc.cmu.edu/%7Ecmccabe/blog_the_setenv_fiasco.html), for the Unix perspective.
  - [GitHub issue #9529](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/9529), for the .NET perspective.

---

<sup>[1] However, *child* processes created via [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) *do* inherit this private copy.</sup>